# URL Changing when configured for multiple languages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have configured by using [this](http://planetmoss.blogspot.com/2007/12/multilingual-moss.html) link.

However the URL is changing as http://server/EN/Pages/default.aspx for the default page.

I want the URL not to change, still I need to have my site displayed for multiple languages.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for Multiple languages in the current version of SharePoint (WSS3/MOSS2007) is to use variations as you've already configured. But this works by having seperate Site hierarchies which require diffenrent URLs

From the SDK documentation for the next version (WSS4/SP2010) it seems as if SharePoint will support different languages for the same Site

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, variations in SharePoint are basically copies of each other under a different path.